# Can we use chef as continuous deployment tool?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, chef-infra, devops, continuous-deployment

I've integrated GitHub, Maven, Nexus and Chef into Jenkins. Now my question is "Can we use chef for continuous deployment" if so how can I deploy my artifact in staging server which is hosted in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "continuous" part of that is entirely up to you, that's just a question of how often you change what versions of things are deployed where. As for the "deployment", that's usually rephrased as "is Chef a good tool for application deployment?". I personally answer yes to that (spoiler warning: I also wrote the `application_*` suite of community cookbooks which exist specifically to make this easier) but it's probably a minority opinion at this point. Containers rule the application world at this point, and most of those ecosystems (Kubernetes, Mesos, Nomad, maybe Swarm if I'm being generous) have their own deployment management tools/systems/whatever. But Chef can do anything a human can so that includes managing those systems too. If you don't feel ready to take the K8s plunge quite yet, then sure, you could do worse than Chef.